# Is it possible to take long-distance X-ray images at a high resolution in Earth's atmosphere?

Tags: scattering, vision, x-rays, imaging, attenuation

It's my understanding that different wavelengths of EM radiation are affected by scattering and attenuation to varying degrees.  Would a camera using only X-rays be able to take a picture of something (for instance) a few miles away with similar detail and clarity to visible light?

This might cross over a little with Science Fiction SE due to a fictional situation prompting the question, and me not needing a mathematically super-precise answer.

Comment: FYI:  This would be off topic and Science Fiction & Fantasy.

Answer (score 1):

X-ray telescopes (XRTs) need to be above the atmosphere as it is opaque to X-rays. So long range X-ray photography in the atmosphere, unless possibly at very high altitudes, would not be very feasible.